# PYTHON - Looping through two directories and compare user input to each line in both files

Tags: python, directory

I have had some success running the program but I'm stuck on the loop and print results part. I want to compare user input from "prefix = input("Please enter the prefix: ")" to two directories. The input can look something like this: /usr/src/, however, the actual filenames can be as long as this:

/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-59/fs/notify/fanotify/Kconfig888c912f2cbef1202df64d94c0e113e0
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-59/fs/notify/inotify/Makefile

The comparisons I'm trying to make are:

- What files are on the first system that are not on the second system?
- What files are on the second system that are not on the first system?
- What files are on both systems, but are different?

I don't expect anyone to finish this for me but I really want to clean it up and correctly print the corresponding outputs. Thank you!

This is what I have so far:

```
system1 = (r"D:\Users\Blah\files\files\spam.list")
system2 = (r"D:\Users\Blah\files\files\eggs.list")
system3 = (r"D:\Users\Blah\files\files\ham.list")



filename1 = input("Enter the filename for the first system: ")
filename2 = input("Enter the filename for the second system: ")
search = input("Please enter the path: ")


data1 = open(system1, 'r',encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore') as f1:
   data2 = open(system2, 'r',encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore') as f2:
      
      data1 = f1.read()
      data2 = f2.read()




for test1 in data1:
    if (test1 in filename1):
       print( search,"is in system 1")
       
else:
    print(search,"is not in system 1")
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things I would like to point out before going into detail on how to solve your concrete problem.

1. I would recommend declaring strings (paths in this case) without `()` as this might easily look like the declaration of a tuple if only viewed briefly. Just use `path1 = r"C:\path"` (or to be more robust and don't depend on the file system have a look on the path modules provided by python [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) [os.path](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html))
2. `fd.read()` returns a string of the file content, you later iterate over that, this means you iterate letter by letter, I'm not sure if that is what you want.
3. You are using context managers not completely correct.
   When using `with open()` you don't need to close `f` explicitly, this is done for you. I'm also not sure if accessing `f` afterward is defined. Moreover, you can also nest context managers.

```py
file_path_1 = "file1.txt"
file_path_2 = "file2.txt"
with open(file_path_1) as f1, open(file_path_2) as f2:
    print(f1.read())
    print(f2.read())
    pass
# no need for f.close()
```

With these things in mind, here is a slight modification of your code to accomplish your task (I think):

```py
import os
import itertools

base_path = r"C:\Users\Blah\Downloads\files\files"

system_paths = [
    os.path.join(base_path, "spam.list"),
    os.path.join(base_path, "eggs.list"),
    os.path.join(base_path, "ham.list")
]

data = []
for path in system_paths:
    with open(path, 'r', encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore') as file:
        data.append(set(line.strip() for line in file))

for (index1, (path1, data1)), (index2, (path2, data2)) \
    in itertools.product(enumerate(zip(system_paths, data)), enumerate(zip(system_paths, data))):
        if index2 <= index1:
            continue
        only_1 = data1 - data2
        only_2 = data2 - data1
        both = data1 & data2
        
        print(f"{index1} - {index2}")
        print(f"Only in system {index1} ({path1}) - {only_1}")
        print(f"Only in system {index2} ({path2}) - {only_2}")
        print(f"In both {index1} ({path1}), {index2} ({path2}) - {both}")
        print()  # empty line at end to separate files
```